# Cocoa and executable files

Tags: cocoa, nsdocument, info-plist

Hey, I am writing a Cocoa app for Mac OS X and I want it to be able to open executable files. That is, files with the 'execute' permission. These files usually do not have a file extension, so I don't know how to specify this in the plist file.

How can I make the Open panel allow the user to select UNIX executables? Thanks in advance.

---

Note that I **don't** want to execute them.

Comment: Do you mean open as in to edit/view the raw binary data of the executable file?

Comment: @Black From yes, and I want the open panel to show files with the execute permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have your application listed in the "Open With..." panel of the Finder for unix -executable file, you have to update your Info.plist for [CFBundleDocumentTypes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html) with the following:

```
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
    <string>Editor</string>
    <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>public.unix-executable</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```